# Orbeon Form Builder - Saving data to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, orbeon

What are the properties that should be set when saving data to orbeon tables in MS SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the following is enough:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="sqlserver"/>
```

This assumes that you have a `<Resource name="jdbc/sqlserver">` in your Tomcat's `server.xml`, inside your `<Context path="/orbeon">`.